# Multiple codes in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to have an excel spreadsheet that will automatically enter the date when information is selected from a drop down menu. But to do this multiple times in a year.   If I create a formula it updates the the date every time it's opened.  So I'm learning that a VBA code needs to be used instead so the date stays when the data is first entered.  I don't want it to change every time the spreadsheet is opened.

I have found one code that will work, but I need this to be done on multiple columns if there is data selected from the drop down menu. For example,  throughout the year, people would continually update the data and I want the date to show automatically when new data is entered into the next column.  Another question too is will this transfer to Google Sheets?

Here's the code I found that seems to work on the first set of columns, E and F

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
'
    Dim RowThatChanged  As Long
'
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E1:E" & Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)) Is Nothing Then     
        RowThatChanged = Target.Row                                                                     
        Range("F" & RowThatChanged).Value = Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy")                                   
        
    End If
End Sub
```

But I need it to do the same thing to these columns when the data is updated,  (G & H), (I & J), (K & L), (M & N), for example.

Comment: "Will this transfer to Google Sheets" - no, Google Sheets uses Apps Script, which is a completely different paradigm than VBA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for excel.

```vb
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range, rng As Range
    
    If Target.CountLarge > 1000 Then Exit Sub 'some reasonable limit on how many cells to handle...
    'in a worksheet code module `Me` is the worksheet itself
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("E:E,G:G,I:I,K:K,M:M")) 'for example
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        For Each c In rng.Cells
            c.Offset(0, 1).Value = Format(Now, "mm-dd-yyyy") 'add date one column over
        Next c
    End If
End Sub
```

However if your real target is Google Sheets you should ask a question specifically about that.

Comment: Thank you Tim! That worked! But you are right, I need to ask about google sheets. I like doing things in Excel and then uploading in google sheets.  But it doesn't always transfer correctly.